# Drupal website breaking in IE 8, 7 - theme not getting applied

Tags: drupal-6, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I need some urgent help with my website : http://studenttribes.com/ . The website is displayed correctly in Chrome and Firefox while its breaking in IE. The most surprising thing is that its breaking even in IE 8 !  The key problem is that the "Theme" is not getting applied at all.

At the moment I am finding the issue pretty baffling . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a custom or contributed theme? There could be many reasons, a little more information might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the "Optimize CSS Files" setting on the Performance page (admin/settings/performance).  If that doesn't help, you may have a typo in your CSS.